# Active Directory SSO Authentican leads to new tab open for every single request

Tags: authentication, directory, saml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are using Snowflake with Active Directory authentication.  When we add the registry entry of  authenticator: externalbrowser for ODBC to work, every query/fetch leads to a new browser tab window to be opened for SAML token.  So if the Excel sheet we are working with has 10 queries, 10 new chrome tab windows open up.

The same applies when we run Python scripts.  We add authenticator='externalbrowser' to the connect command and then each and every query in the script leads to the opening of a new browser tab to get the SAML token.  This of course is quite annoying since we end up with 100's of browser window 
tabs being opened.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design since you are specifying the authentication method as 'externalbrowser', however it only opens a new browser for each *connection* that is made.  Check to see if each of your queries establishes a new connection object.

What you want is to open a connection object once, then use a *cursor* object from the connection each time you need to execute a query.